# Correct way of setting up network teaming for maximum throughput in Windows Server

Tags: networking, switch, windows-server-2016, lacp

We have a backup server with 4x1GB NICs. All 4 NICs are configures as a single Team (Switch Independent, Dynamic).
NIC 1-2 are connected to SW01, NIC 3-4 are connected to SW02 and the switches are interconnected on 4 ports.

```
NIC1,2=====SW01
           ||||
NIC3,4=====SW02
```

The switchport trunk types are LACP between the switches. There is nothing configured on the switchports connecting to the backup server

Now, the speed of the Team is 4GB but the server does not utilise more than 1 NIC at a time due to the way it is configured

The question is how do I configure the server and the switches to maximise throughput of the network card(s) to allow the backups to complete quicker?
The bottleneck is not the trunk between the switches

The server is Windows Server 2016 Datacenter, the switches are HP E2910al-48G, not stacked

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Switch independent mode the switch does not know the presence of your NIC team on the server. In this case the links are working in a load balance mode which is handled by the Windows Server so the maximum bandwidth is limited to the capacity of a single NIC interface (1GBit/s in this case).

If you want to aggregate the available bandwidth then you have to setup and LACP trunk between the servers and the switches too. Set the teaming mode on the servers to LACP, loadballancing mode to Dynamic and no standby adapter. Then configure the appropriate LACP trunks on the switches too.

[Some more info](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt179276.aspx#bkmk_teaming)